# Discretizing my continuous system in Matlab

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, linear-systems, discretization

I was hoping someone could help me with conducting my discretization in MATLAB.
I have a linear system with known data: sampling interval $T$, system matrix $\mathbf{A}$, input matrix $\mathbf{B}$, output matrix $\mathbf{C}$ and direct feed-through $\mathbf{D}$.

Now I need to manually compute the discrete system in MATLAB, I know that:
$x[k+1] = \phi x[k]+\gamma u[k]$

Now the question is how to compute $\phi$ and $\gamma$ in MATLAB, I hope someone can help me there, I know that $\phi = e^{\mathbf{A}T}$ and $\gamma = \int_0^T e^{\mathbf{A}x}\mathbf{B}dx$.
I am not very familiar anymore with MATLAB syntax, it would be huge help if someone could show me how to type this in MATLAB, then I can start analyzing the system for myself. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand what your modeling of course, but is your question really just how to do the integral in MATLAB?

Comment: Matlab has a function that does that, but I think it's in the Control Systems Toolbox (I don't use Matlab, so -- I dunno).  Have you done a websearch?  In Scilab the function is called `dscr`; some of those function names are the same between Matlab and Scilab.

Comment: @Engineer I have found it out now, I forgot that there was such an easy function for the matrix exponential. It was my problem getting that one in the integral without using Cayley-Hamilton manually, but now I have found it thanks :)